# Twilio whatsapp location

Tags: whatsapp, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, flash-message, twilio-python

Please let me know how to send and recive the location through twilio and python. like longitude and latitude and  I need users to be able to share their current location with the bot.

Comment: Not obvious where **exactly** you are stuck on this. Did you [read the guide](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052128874-Can-I-share-my-location-or-receive-location-information-on-WhatsApp-)? That document also links to [some API examples](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/message-features#location-messages-with-whatsapp). We can only try to help fix your _"not working"_ code. Try something then ask here.

Answer (score 0):

go to the site package & search for 'C:\Users\yuvraj.yamgar\anaconda3\envs\new_project\Lib\site-packages\rasa\core\channels\twilio.py' for this path open that twilio.py

```
  @twilio_webhook.route("/webhook", methods=["POST"])
    async def message(request: Request) -> HTTPResponse:
        sender = request.form.get("From", None)
        text = request.form.get("Body", None)

        lat = request.form.get("Latitude",None)
        long = request.form.get("Longitude",None)
        city =  request.form.get("city",None)
        metadata = self.get_metadata(request)
        
        if lat is not None and long is not None:
        
            if text is None:
                text = '/locationdata'
            if metadata is None:
                metadata ={'LocationData':{'lat':lat,'long':long,'state':city}}
                print(type(metadata),'printing type of')
                string = str(metadata)
                print(string,"location")
                text = string
                print(lat,long,city)
            else:
                metadata =[self.get_metadata(request),{'LocationData':{'lat':lat,'long':long,'state':city}}]
```

use this code you will get lat & long